# Need some help converting cvpixelbuffer data to a jpeg/png in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cvpixelbuffer

So I'm trying to get a jpeg/png representation of the grayscale depth maps that are typically used in iOS image depth examples. The depth data is stored in each jpeg as aux data. I've followed some tutorials and I have no problem rendering this gray scale data to the screen, but I can find no way to actually save it as a jpeg/png representation. I'm pretty much using this code: https://www.raywenderlich.com/168312/image-depth-maps-tutorial-ios-getting-started

The depth data is put into a `cvpixelbuffer` and manipulated accordingly. I believe it's in the format `kCVPixelFormatType_DisparityFloat32`.

While I'm able to see this data represented accordingly on the screen, I'm unable to use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` or `UIImageJPGRepresentation`. Sure, I could manually capture a screenshot, but that's not really ideal.

I have a suspicion that the `cvpixelbuffer` data format is not compatible with these `UIImage` functions and that's why I can't get them to spit out an image.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried?

Comment: You can create a `CIImage` from a `CVPixelBuffer` with `init(cvPixelBuffer pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer)`, then you can create the `UIImage` from the `CIImage` using `UIImage`s `init(ciImage: CIImage)`

Comment: @DennisW. So this is what I'm doing:  


`let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: depthDataMap)  
depthDataMapImage = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage)  
let grey = UIImagePNGRepresentation(depthDataMapImage!)`

Comment: @DennisW. Sorry about the formatting. Those should be on different lines.

When I debug the code and look at the variables in xcode, I see:  

`depthDataMap = (CVPixelBuffer?) 0x00000001d412c9e0`
`depthDataMapImage = (UIImage?) 0x00000001d40a61e0`
`ciImage = (CIImage?) 0x00000001d4004f30`
`grey = (Data?) nil`

So the issue seems to be that grey = nil, and I'm not sure why that is unless the pixelbuffer format isn't supported.

Answer (score 1):

Posting a swift code sample in case anyone wants to use it.

```
let ciimage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: depthBuffer) // depth cvPixelBuffer
let depthUIImage = UIImage(ciImage: ciimage)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// CVPixelBuffer to UIImage
let ciImageDepth            = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: cvPixelBufferDepth)
let contextDepth:CIContext  = CIContext.init(options: nil)
let cgImageDepth:CGImage    = contextDepth.createCGImage(ciImageDepth, from: ciImageDepth.extent)!
let uiImageDepth:UIImage    = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageDepth, scale: 1, orientation: UIImage.Orientation.up)

// Save UIImage to Photos Album
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(uiImageDepth, nil, nil, nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to convert to a CGImage first. Ended up doing cvPixelBuffer to CIImage to CGImage to UIImage.

Comment: You can use VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer to go to CGImage from cvPixelBuffer.